# Crossroads.js - route selection

Tags: javascript, url-routing

Could somebody help me with routing rules configuration, please?
I got problem with route optional parameters constraints.

the route named 'offerRegionCategoryTitle' should be invoked for /{region}/{category}/{title}/:page: url pattern - and this works properly,

but when I try to invoke
/{region}/{category}/:page: url (etc. /pomorskie/programowanie/1) then the 'offerRegionCategoryTitle' route is handled.

I think that the problem is in route rules configuration.
Could somebody help me please?

Source code:
AppRouting: http://jsfiddle.net/kppfP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both routes essentially match the "same" strings. You have 3 dynamic segments (`{region}/{category}/:page:` or `{region}/{category}/{title}`) and there is not enough info for the router to distinguish between both. If `:page:` is always numeric and `{title}` isn't you can add more rules to make sure it doesn't match the wrong route:

```
var catRoute = crossroads.addRoute('/{region}/{category}/:page:');
catRoute.rules = {
  page : /^\d+$/ // should be numeric
};

var titleRoute = crossroads.addRoute('/{region}/{category}/{title}/:page:');
titleRoute.rules = {
  title : function(val){
     return isNaN(val); // title can't be numeric (should contain at least one char)
  },
  page : /^\d+$/ // should be numeric
};
```

See [documentation about Route.rules](http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/#route-rules) and [examples page](https://github.com/millermedeiros/crossroads.js/wiki/Examples) for more info.